# Determining public IP in C# and comparing to a hostname

Tags: c#, comparison, ip, router, hostname

I have a program in C# that I want to get a news feed from a server I setup in my basement. I also want to setup this program so it can work locally. To do this I THINK I need to compare the resolved ip of my dyndns.biz hostname to my router's public ip (I have dynamic ip and a client on my server updating the ip of the hostname) and thus determine if the hostname needs to be used or the local ip of the server (192.168.0.100) or the hostname. I already have code to connect to the ftp server assuming I can get the right usage of the hostname versus the localized IP.

Edit: Anyways, in summary because I realized this might not look like a question, how can I determine a) the resolved IP of the hostname and b) the public IP of my router in a C# app

Comment: I got lost in all the text there. Are you asking how to get the IP address of a domain name (ie. your "dyndns.biz" hostname)?

Comment: I realized it didn't quite look like a question, updated.

Comment: Assimilater's issue is something I encountered as well: Most routers won't allow you to access your local network from a machine on the network using the public/internet IP (essentially a loopback). So he has to detect that case (hostname's IP == local internet IP -> use LAN IP/loopback instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this.
Just open your `hosts` file (found in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) and add your dyndns hostname routing it to loopback. That way you don't have to add any workaround code to your final application to prevent it from even asking your DNS or router:

```
127.0.0.1 yourhostname.dyndns.biz
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Modify it on the computer executing your program and instead of `127.0.0.1` use the server's LAN ip.

Comment: it made sense to me, but in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: Quick question, (i ask partially because this app is going to be used by family members) suppose a particular laptop is running this app and it needs to be used both inside and outside the LAN, is there an easier out short of modifying the hosts file every time the LAN is entered and exited?

Comment: If the app is used by family members only inside/outside that particular LAN ... how about checking the local computer's IP address(es) instead and ask the user where he is if it changes/is unknown? Otherwise your initial idea might be better (which would require a third computer/outside server to tell you your ip; just parse the output of any of those "What's my IP?" sites).

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the IP address of a hostname, use the following code:

```
IPAddress[] addresses = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.cnn.com");
```

To obtain your public IP address of your router or local network, you need to talk to an outside system that can tell you that part, and unfortunately I don't know if there is any such system that is free to use as well as easy to use from a program.

Comment: Note, if anyone can improve on the above answer, feel free to just copy anything and everything (that is useful) into your own, and I'd be happy to delete mine.

Comment: Although Mario posed a better solution, I'm sure I'll use this knowledge in the future :). Thank you!